# Rust/Rocket: how do I return multiple pages/documents when a user makes an HTTP request?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I'm trying to return multiple documents (`index.html`, `style.css`) in an HTTP response when a user makes a single HTTP request. How do I go about doing this? I'm thinking using something like a `std::io::File` instance to return these, but this hasn't worked out so far.

The function and route below are the ones the user interacts with when visiting the website for the first time.

I have read Rocket's documentation about [`NamedFile`](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket/response/struct.NamedFile.html) and [`StaticFiles`](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket_contrib/serve/struct.StaticFiles.html) but I'm not so sure that these are the correct solutions in this scenario.

```
#[get("/")]
fn index() -> Response<'static> {
    let mut response = Response::new();
    response.set_status(Status::Ok);
    response
}
```

Comment: This is not the proper way to serve a website, separate files should be served on separate paths. What problem are you trying to solve? If you really want a single response, you can embed the CSS file within `<style>` tags in your HTML. Or if you just want people to download the files, consider returning a ZIP. Any other way to shoe-horn two files into a single response will likely not be handled properly by a browser.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the problem that my CSS won't be requested by the browser. But if I include the CSS in the HTML, will the browser make an automatic request for the CSS? And if so, should I have a separate route for handling the CSS requests?

Comment: yes and yes, see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) for how to add an external css file to your html. the `StaticFiles` handler from rocket allows you to just have your index.html and style.css in a folder and not have to worry about making all the routes explicitly

Comment: Ah alright I see. In that case the `StaticFiles` makes a lot more sense to use. Thanks!